Dynamic SQL select statement (DB2 LUW v11.5) has a very high log_disk_wait_time
I'm running DB2 v11.5.9.0 CSB 42449 on zLinux SLES15 SP5.
I'm tuning a dynamic SQL select statement using activity & package cache event monitor.
Looking at the performance data of these event monitors, I see that this dynamic SQL statement has a stmt_exec_time of 178418 milliseconds.
The biggest wait component is the log_disk_wait_time element with a wait time of 162226 milliseconds.
I can provide the SQL statement if needed but I can already say this statement joins 6 tables using left joins and also performs a group by.
Basically my question boils down to : why can log activity affect the performance of a select statement ? Put in other words : why is the agent working on this select has to wait for log buffers to be flushed to disk ?
Manually re-ran this statement : no performance issues

Study the db2exfmt plan output, and compare estimates with actuals  . Things are sometimes not what they appear to be.

The tables used in the select statement might be heavily changed, you have cur_commit db config parameter turned on, and db2 might actively read logs to get you committed versions of the corresponding rows.
